# How to remove final character in a number of strings?

Tags: python, string, trailing

I have a number of strings that I would like to remove the last character of each string. When I try out the code below it removes my second line of string instead of removing the last element. Below is my code:

**Code**

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    seqs=file.read().splitlines()
    seqs=seqs[:-1]
```

**test.txt**

```
ABCABC
XYZXYZ
```

**Output**

```
ABCABC
```

**Desired output**

```
ABCAB
XYZXY
```

Comment: Think about what `seqs` is after the first assignment... It's a list of all *lines* (i.e. a list of strings). You need another loop to modify each line. List comprehension will be your friend in this situation.

Comment: You are dealing with array of arrays of strings, not arrays of strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this `seqs=seqs[:-1]`

to a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
seqs=[val[:-1] for val in seqs]
```

**Note:**

- The problem in your old method is that `seq` is a list of strings i.e `["ABCABC","XYZXYZ"]`. You are just getting the item before last item `ABCABC` which explains the output.
- What I have done is get the strings from the list and omit it's last character.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for seq in file:
        print seq.strip()[:-1]
```

This iterates through every line in the file and prints the line omitting the last character

Comment: Your method would be less memory consuming then mine good answer :).

Comment: Rather than `print`, you could also `yield` the value.  Then you can write `for value in truncated():` and do further processing on each truncated value.

Answer (score 4):

`file.read().splitlines()` returns a list. Therefore the following could solve your problem:

```
enter with open('test.txt') as file:
    data = list(map(lambda x: x[:-1], file.read().splitlines()))
```

Then you can join the list back into a string: `"\n".join(data)`

Answer (score 2):

`seqs` is a list of lines. You need to loop through the lines to access each line:

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    seq = file.read().splitlines()
    for word in seq:
        word = word[:-1]
        print word
```